# computing scientific numbers in java

Tags: java, number-formatting

I am trying to add different numbers from a file in java.

Numbers can be of format : "1.13206e+06"

How can I parse this number to reflect actual value in java??

Thanks

Comment: Reading your *"doesn't work"* comment that you made to Devon_C_Miller, I recommend you the best paper ever on the subject, which is a must read: *"What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic"* (and, yup, it's still hosted at Sun ;) http://docs.sun.com/source/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `Double.parseDouble`:

```
double d = Double.parseDouble("1.13206e+06");
```

This works fine with scientific notation.

Answer (score 3):

You want to look at [Double.parseDouble](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#parseDouble%28java.lang.String%29)